# How to get registration data from a portlet/jsp

Tags: websphere-portal

Where does WebSphere Portal 8.5 store user registration data that is entered through sign up form? I.e. user id, password, first, last name, email etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Portal doesn't store any user info on its own.

It uses PUMA and VMM to talk to users store registry. See more here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.0.0/plan/plan_vmm_int.dita.

Guess you can look at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/websphere/PUMA_scenarios.pdf to figure out how you can retrieve user information from the user registry.

Comment: adding the default locations - OOTB it is a filerepository for development usage
Usually an LDAP or multiple LDAP environments are attached below VMM or a complete custom implementation can be applied

Answer (score 0):

This data is stored in PUMA.
In the WAS console, you will be able to view the LDAP configurations.
Login to the WAS console and go to Security > Global security > Federated repositories > Manage repositories > PortalLdap
Under LDAP server, the "Primary Host Name" will show the server where PUMA is configured.